# section или  div

Tags: html5

Везде пишется по разному о значении тега  section.
Как правильно разметить эту страницу

```
       <header></header>
       <section id="content">
           <section id="news"></section>
           <section id="info"></section>
       </section>
       <footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно спецификации HTML5, рекомендуется использовать div в самый крайний случай. Плюс, чем Вам не устраивает Ваша разметка?

Comment: http://css-live.ru/articles/element-section.html

Comment: Тогда в Вашем случае используйте везде div.